# Use regular expressions to flexibly modify a string

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I want to insert an underscore between all pairingss of letters (A-Z) and a limited set of numbers (e.g., 2-5). I can detect the presence of this pattern using `str_detect()`, but if I want to replace these patterns I clearly can't use the regular expression as I am attempting below.

Is there a way to maintain the letters and numbers from x as they are modified by the `str_replace_all(`) function?

My goal is to convert

```
old <- c("B0", "B1", "B2", "B3", "BA4") 
new <- c("B0", "B1", "B_2", "B_3", "BA")
```

I have tried :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

x <- c("B0", "B1", "B2", "B3", "BA4")

str_detect(x, "^[A-Z][2-5]")

str_replace_all(x, "^[A-Z][2-5]", "[A-Z]_[2-5]")

[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[1] "B0" "B1" "[A-Z]_[2-5]" "[A-Z]_[2-5]" "BA4"
```

Comment: Isn't this just `gsub("2", "_2", x)` ? Or for numbers 2-5: `gsub("([2345])", "_\\1", x)
`

Answer (score 3):

We can capture as a group and replace with the backreference of the captured group

```
str_replace_all(substr(x, 1, 2), "^([A-Z])([2-5])", "\\1_\\2")
#[1] "B0"  "B1"  "B_2" "B_3" "BA"
```